# Saving filtered results from an Excel workbook to a CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have an Excel workbook with a lot of rows in it. I filter it using the values of one column and then I want to save the filtered results to a CSV file. When I do "Save as..." I get all the rows. I can copy paste the filtered results to another sheet and save from there but I'd rather not. It's Excel 2003 primarily.

Comment: AFAIK, it may not be possible until if we write some macro.

Comment: Install ASAP Utilities and you can do "Remove Hidden Rows" before you save the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

Use an advanced filter to filter and paste the results as values into a new worksheet in one go which at least saves a step and is probably more reproducable in fewer clicks every time after the first. You can also select only the columns you want and in any order.

Debra's site is probably the best resource for examples on this:

[www.contextures.com][1]

[1]: http:// www.contextures.com

Comment: I get a `You can only copy filtered data to the active sheet` error when trying this with Excel 2007 Advanced Filter 'Copy to another location' option.

Answer (score 1):

CSV format will not save formatting, formulas or filtering, as you have discovered. You must either, only copy what you want to save to a new sheet and save it as CSV or save to an excel format.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table. Click on any location in your table, Click Insert, select Pivot Table, then set up the columns you want to keep. You can filter a Pivot table then save as CSV or text (tab delimited). It saves only the filtered pivot table.